# Flex - how to validate that a URL goes to a valid website?

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible to programmatically validate that a URL goes to a valid website in Flex?  I have some procedurally generated URLs and I want to check if the website exists before making the URL visible.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you, maybe it's something more advanced than you need, but can give you an idea.
http://shashankkulkarni.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/validating-if-the-url-exists-or-not-on-client-side-with-flex/     If it's me know and put it as answer, if it helps another.

Comment: You can validate whether the domain is accurate using a Regex.  Beyond that; you have to make a call and see if you get an error back or not.  And you can't do that from a browser based Flex app if you're trying to access a domain other than the one your SWF was served from; so you'll have to use a Server side proxy to do the load checking.

Comment: [shashankkulkarni.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/...](http://shashankkulkarni.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/validating-if-the-url-exists-or-not-on-client-side-with-flex/) The approach in this link seems to work pretty well. Thanks, matilu.